# laravel backpack show only not disable elements

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a table employers where I can disable the single row. So when the user load the page I want to show only the not disable employers but I want also have a button for show only the disable users.
So I use in my setup

$this->crud->addClause("is_disable",true)

and this works fine.
The problem is that when the user click on disable filter, I have an error
because I have the filter addClause("is_disable",true) enable but now I want addClause("is_disable",false)...When the user click on disable button filter I have to remove the clause addClause("is_disable",true) but I don't know how to do. The are others path?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fourth parameter you can use for `addFilter()` - it's the fallback logic. That closure will be called when the filter is NOT active. I think that's exactly what you're looking for:

```
$this->crud->addFilter([ // add a "simple" filter called Disabled
  'type'  => 'simple',
  'name'  => 'disabled',
  'label' => 'Disabled',
],
false, // the simple filter has no values above
function () { // if the filter is active
    // do nothing; no filtering is actually needed
},
function () { // if the filter is NOT active
    $this->crud->addClause('is_disable', true);
});
```